# How to add hint in android spinner?

Tags: java, android, json, android-spinner

I know there are lot of questions related to my questions, i looked at those solutions but couldn't able to get help from them. So that's why i am posting this question.

My `app` is getting a `json` data from a `web-service`. Below is my `json` result

```
{"users":[{"Id":"1","Name":"Faisal"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Salman"},{"Id":"3","Name":"Asim"},{"Id":"4","Name":"Asad"},{"Id":"5","Name":"Mateen"},{"Id":"6","Name":"Omar"},{"Id":"7","Name":"Usama"}]}
```

From the above data i am displaying only `Names` in an android spinner. Below is my `Config.java` code

```
public class Config {

//JSON URL
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/MobileApp/index.php";

//Tags used in the JSON String

public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";

public static final String TAG_ID = "Id";

//JSON array name
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "users";

}
```

For `MainActivity.java` see below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

//Declaring an Spinner
private Spinner spinner;

//An ArrayList for Spinner Items
private ArrayList<String> users;

//JSON Array
private JSONArray result;

//TextViews to display details
private TextView textViewResult;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Initializing the ArrayList
    users = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Initializing Spinner
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
    //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself
    // we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Initializing TextView

    textViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //This method will fetch the data from the URL
    getData();
}

private void getData() {

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getUsers(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getUsers(JSONArray j) {

    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i =0; i<j.length(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list

            users.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



 //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner

    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, users));

}


//Method to get student name of a particular position
private String getName(int position)
{
    String name = "";
    try
    {
        //Getting object of given index
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
        //Fetching name from that object
        name = json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

//Method to get student Id of a particular position
private String getId (int postion)
{
    String Id="";
    try{
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(postion);

        Id = json.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Id;
}

//this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Appending the values to textview for a selected item
   // textViewResult.setText("");
    textViewResult.setText("Hi " + getName(position) + " your ID is " + getId(position));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    textViewResult.setText("");

 }
}
```

When i run the app the below result is shown

[image]

I want is whenever i run `app` the first `text` in the `spinner` would be like `Select a name`

In my layout file i did tried `android:hint="Select a name"` but it didn't work as it shows me nothing in the spinner

[image]

**Update 1**
As suggested by `Selin Marvan K` i have done the following

```
 //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            users.add("Select a name");
            users.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
```

When i run the `app` following result is shown

[image]

On the suggestion of `Selin Marvan K` i have the following

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Appending the values to textview for a selected item
   // textViewResult.setText("");

    if(!getName(position).equals("select a name")) {
        textViewResult.setText("Hi " + getName(position-1) + " your ID is " + getId(position-1));
    }
    //textViewResult.setText("Hi " + getName(position) + " your ID is " + getId(position));
}
```

Bellow are the result which i am seeing

[image]

It should not show an text on first run also in `dropdown`.

It does show me my hint but in result it still displaying me the first name and id. When i select the second name the 3rd name and id is displaying

I don't know what to do. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451499/android-spinner-set-default-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810610/how-to-set-hint-text-for-spinner

Comment: Let me know whether that one worked or not.

Comment: @SoumyaRauth sure i'll let you know in a while

Comment: @SoumyaRauth i am unable to understand the solution :(

Comment: Did u add the dependency to gradle?

Comment: Yes i added the dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135687/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-soumya-rauth).

Comment: @SoumyaRauth can you look into my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42438584/6854117) ?

Answer (score 0):

**I think spinner have no hint**

**But i have small solution**

your code is

```
users.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));//this will add name to user array list
```

before add user names to arraylist, put below code

ie.add your hint to your array

```
users.add("your hint");
eg:users.add("select name");
```

i think it will help you

Comment: Ok, i'll try and let you know

Comment: It didn't help me out, all it shows me the empty spinner

Comment: Sorry my bad, my `xampp` server was not running, kindly see the update

Answer (score 0):

**use if condition**

```
if(!getName(posission).equals("select a name"))
{
    textViewResult.setText("Hi " + getName(position-1) + " your ID is " + getId(position-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In onItemSelected() function**

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
 //Appending the values to textview for a selected item
 // textViewResult.setText("");
  if(!getName(posission).equals("select a name"))
  {
    textViewResult.setText("Hi " + getName(position-1) + " your ID is " + getId(position-1));
  }  }
```