# Unable to add hint in android spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I have a `spinner` that behaves like a `dropdown` in my `android application`. I am developing the app in `android studio`. The spinner get data from the `api`. At run time it gets `usernames` from `API` and shows in the `spinner`. When app runs it shows the `username` and `ID` of the selected user like shown in below image

[image]

Now i want to add hint so i searched many articles and found many solutions and i follow the easiest of them. For more understanding please see the below code

```
 try
        {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonArray = jobj.getJSONArray("users");

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Users user = new Users();

                user.setId(jsonObject.optString("Id"));
                user.setName(jsonObject.optString("Name"));
                users.add(user);

                userList.add("Select a username");// i add this as a hint
                userList.add(jsonObject.optString("Name"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now on **onPostExecute()** method

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args)
    {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, userList));

        // Spinner on item click listener

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                textViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

                // Set the text followed by the position

                // Set the text followed by the position
                if(!users.get(position).getName().equals("Select a username")) {
                    textViewResult.setText(" " + users.get(position - 1).getName() + "  " + users.get(position - 1).getId());
                }else {

                    textViewResult.setText("Hi " + users.get(position).getName() + " your ID is " + users.get(position).getId());
                    UserId = String.valueOf(users.get(position).getId());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    _latitude.setText("");
                    _longitude.setText("");
                    Latitude = null;
                    Longitude = null;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                textViewResult.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
```

When i run the application the app crashes while giving me the below error

```
Process: com.example.accurat.myapp, PID: 30382
                                                                       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
                                                                           at com.example.accurat.myapp.MainActivity$DownloadJSON$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:494)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

This error hits at the point `textViewResult.setText(" " + users.get(position - 1).getName() + "  " + users.get(position - 1).getId());`

**Update 1**

following the answer of `Junaid Hafeez` i have done the following

```
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Users user = new Users();

                user.setId(jsonObject.optString("Id"));
                user.setName(jsonObject.optString("Name"));
                users.add(user);


                userList.add(jsonObject.optString("Name"));

            }
            userList.add(0, "Select a username"); // after for loop ended i add `select a username` at `0` index
```

after that in `postExecute()` method i have done the following

```
 @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                textViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

                // Set the text followed by the position

                // Set the text followed by the position
                if(position>0)
                {
                    textViewResult.setText("Hi " + users.get(position).getName() + " your ID is " + users.get(position).getId());

                    UserId = String.valueOf(users.get(position).getId());

                    _latitude.setText("");
                    _longitude.setText("");
                    Latitude = null;
                    Longitude = null;
                }
                else {


                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
```

The result i get is below

[image]

It does show me the hint, but when i select any username it shows me the `name` and `id` of the next username as shown in below image

[image]

I am stuck to it and couldn't find any solution

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: add the default value as hint at at 0 place of array to act as hint

Comment: you should add first item in your list for hint like Select Item.

Comment: @SouravGanguly can you please provide me a snippet ?

Comment: add default item in your `userList` like this `userList.add("select user");` on `onPreExecute` method.

Comment: why are you doing `position-1`?

Comment: @aksacha added it, still facing same exception

Comment: @VivekMishra if i don't do it then it will automatically show me the first name and id while the `text` on the  `spinner` is `select a name`

Comment: I think u have overrided the 0th element of the userlist with the hint

Comment: @sravs what to do then ?

Comment: Faisal is there in the list right..so it is not overridden..try textViewResult.setText("Hi " + users.get(position-1).getName() + " your ID is " + users.get(position-1).getId());

Comment: @sravs you means ' if(position>0)
                    {
                        textViewResult.setText("Hi " + users.get(position-1).getName() + " your ID is " + users.get(position-1).getId());

                        UserId = String.valueOf(users.get(position).getId());

                        _latitude.setText("");
                        _longitude.setText("");
                        Latitude = null;
                        Longitude = null;
                    }
                    else {


                    }'  like this ?

Comment: yes..use position-1 instead of position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136549/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-sravs).

Comment: @sravs it's working thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably what you are doing is, you are clicking on first item of you spinner, where the `position = 0` and doing this `position - 1` in your `setText` which makes the index `-1` that is actually not exists and crashes.
Secondly you are doing this

```
 userList.add("Select a username");// i add this as a hint
```

in your loop, which is adding new item on each iteration. 
what you need to do is

once you have complete list of your data, 
just add hint on its 0 index like this

```
userList.add(0, "Select a username");
```

and in your onClick, check weather `position > 0` then do your work otherwise ignore as user clicked on hint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am still unable to completely resolve the issue, i have updated the question can you please see it ?

Comment: @faisal1208 are you sure `users` and `usersList` are the same lists? you have added new item in `usersList` and trying to get from `users` in your click method. abviosly it will show next item as 0 index was missed becuase of hint text and I think you won't have hint test in `users`

Comment: both users and user list get data from same json, if you want anything that will make things clear please tell me

Comment: simply put a break point when you click spinner item and check what you have on first index of your Users list.

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.keshav.spinnerhintexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_submit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                if (position == getCount()) {
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
                }

                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
            }

        };


        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.add("Daily");
        adapter.add("Two Days");
        adapter.add("Weekly");
        adapter.add("Monthly");
        adapter.add("Three Months");
        adapter.add("Select a Item"); //This is the text that will be displayed as hint.


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount()); //set the hint the default selection so it appears on launch.
        // spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String item=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.e("keshav","selectedItem is ->"  + item);

                if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select a Item")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Select an Item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected Item is -> "+item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

-------------------Xml File ----------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.keshav.spinnerhintexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Use below library for the hint spinner

[Hint Spinner library](https://github.com/rathodchintan/HintSpinnerAdapter?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2698)